# Why changing member function of variable valid in JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function, class, memory

```
class T{
  func(){return 0;}
}

let var1 = new T; 
var1.func = ()=>{return 1;}
console.assert((new T).func() != var1.func())
```

1. Is JS member function just a key(functionName)-value(functionPointer) pair? So every variable will take 64-bit memory?
2. Does JS has something like virtual Function Table(C++)?
3. Will adding a virtual function that is only used by some DerivedClass into BaseClass worsen performance? which means I should implement it this way:

```
class Base{
  //loadAsset(){}; //will make every derived class waste memory?
}

class BaseWithAsset extends Base{
  loadAsset(){};  //all derived class that need to loadAsset should extend BaseWithAsset
}
```

4. Is static member function preferable (to save memory)?

I used to develope game with cpp. now webgame with typescript.

Comment: A member function is just another member variable.  Objects have a list of name/object pairs.  The object can be a value, or a function, or any other object.  When you call `T.func()`, it just looks up the name `func`.  That happens to return a function object, and the `()` operator will call that function.  It's much more generalized than C++, and much more profligate with memory.

Comment: @TimRoberts  Is static member function preferable?  Does such practice has downside？

Comment: No, the concept does not apply.  All functions are methods of some object.  Even global functions are methods of the global object (called `window` in a browser).  Javascript has grown into an interesting language, but you need to take the time to learn it, instead of trying to treat it like C++.  It's quite different.